# Laravel eloquent model how to pass in value from function inside controller to render()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can one pass in the value from a function inside a controller to the render()?

For example:

```
class NewClass extends Component
{
   // $a is being passed in. Already defined
   public function DoSomething($a){
      return $a;
   }

   public function render()
   {
      return view('FirstPage', [
       'posts' => NewModel::
       // HOW TO PASS IN value of $a
       where('Value1', '=', $a)
  ]);
 }
}
```

EDIT:
I do not know how to call the method of DoSomething inside of the where(), as the $a is not defined in the render().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store the value in a class property or variable to be accessible within the `render()` method.

```
class NewClass extends Component {
    // Declare a class property to hold the value of $a
    protected $a;

    public function DoSomething($a){
        // Assign the value of $a to the class property
        $this->a = $a;

        return $a;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('FirstPage', [
            'posts' => NewModel::where('Value1', '=', $this->a)->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```